# How to use a reflect.Type to perform a type assertion

Tags: go, reflection

I know reflection is generally frowned upon in go but for my current purposes Im pretty sure it is the best solution.

Essentially my project is cli tool which will output an xml query based on incoming commands and return the corresponding result.

There is some boiler plate code for each command request where default values are populated and supplied values validated.

So I have a series of Command objects based on a Command struct as follows:

```
type Command struct {
    Name        string
    Request     interface{}
    RequestType reflect.Type
    Response    interface{}

    RegisterFunc func(parentCmd *cobra.Command, cmd *Command) error
}
```

For the most part I really don't care about the types of the request/response (just xml encode/decode). However I need to briefly cast it to a concrete type to validate with struct annotations
So for example I might do something like this:

```
    var ccReq *CreateCredentialRequest
    var set bool
    if ccReq, set = command.Request.(*CreateCredentialRequest); !set {
        log.Fatal(errors.New("invalid request type"))
    }

    result, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(ccReq)
    if err != nil {
        println("error: " + err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

However in an ideal would I would like to handle this generically for all commands, something like this:

```
    var ccReq *CreateCredentialRequest
    var set bool
    if ccReq, set = command.Request.(command.RequestType); !set {
        log.Fatal(errors.New("invalid request type"))
    }
```

However this results in the error:

> command.RequestType is not a type

So, how can I store the value of a type for a later type assertion

Note: Following discussion in comments with JimB it seems that i do not actually need the concrete type for validation purposes (interface is fine) but I still need further down to assert the response type to provide a custom response handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`reflect.Type` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type):

> Type values are comparable, such as with the == operator, so they can be used as map keys. Two Type values are equal if they represent identical types.

If you want to compare underlying types, compare the `reflect.Type` values directly:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(command.Request) != command.RequestType {
    log.Fatal(errors.New("invalid request type"))
}
```

Comment: thanks, that solves part of my issue but I need a handle on the original request type to run the validation as well, how can I actually perform the type assertion using the reflect.Type

Comment: @WebweaverD: what do you mean by "actually perform the type assertion"? What exactly do you want to do with the `ccReq` value?

Comment: I need to validate it - I'm using struct annotations on the original type to define validation rules so need the concrete type for the govalidator package - see line 'result, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(ccReq)', validation of the type was just for good measure really

Comment: `ValidateStruct` takes an `interface{}`, you don't need to assert or convert anything to pass `command.Request` to it.

Comment: ah, good spot, thanks - so I dont actually need it for that purpose but as my current code stands I will still need it for the response handler further down (sorry not included in question as I presumed irrelevant) - it may be that I can avoid this with a code rethink but do you know if what I ask is possible - making a concrete type from reflect.Type and an interface

Comment: @WebweaverD: you're going to have to show an example of what you mean. You can of course initialize `reflect.Value` from a `reflect.Type`, or you convert from a `reflect.Value` to a "Convertible" `reflect.Type`, or simply call a method on the `reflect.Value`, but I don't know what it is you want to do.

Comment: thanks for your help - I'm going to accept and close for now whilst I clarify in my own mind exactly what i need to do and if required I shall return with something more concise